# Directive 'StrictModes' is not allowed within a Match block

Tags: security, ssh-tunneling, sshd, amazon-ec2

I am building a network of Raspberry Pi [ADS-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_dependent_surveillance_%E2%80%93_broadcast) receivers.  Several nodes placed at different locations: home, lodge, parents, maybe more to come... They are all set up to [phone home](https://www.tunnelsup.com/raspberry-pi-phoning-home-using-a-reverse-remote-ssh-tunnel/) to an [Amazon-EC2](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/) using a reverse ssh tunnel.

What I really want to achieve is some way of distinction of which node is which and what local port to use for SSH to the node.

Since `sudo netstat -tlpe --numeric-ports | grep sshd` show what users is running the process I am thinking to have one user for each tunnel.  I want to restrict the users for SSH reverse tunnel only. Preferably I want to keep all node (multiple) keys in the same `authorized_keys` file and keep `StrictModes yes` for all other users.

I ended up running theese commands:

```
sudo groupadd sshtungrp
sudo useradd sshtunnel -m -d /home/sshtunnel -s /bin/true -g sshtungrp
while read p; do sudo useradd $p -M -d /home/sshtunnel -s /bin/true -g sshtungrp; done < users.txt;

sudo -u sshtunnel mkdir /home/sshtunnel/.ssh
sudo -u sshtunnel vim /home/sshtunnel/.ssh/authorized_keys

sudo -u sshtunnel chmod 750 /home/sshtunnel
sudo -u sshtunnel chmod 750 /home/sshtunnel/.ssh
sudo -u sshtunnel chmod 640 /home/sshtunnel/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

To `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I've added:

```
Match Group *,!sshtungrp
        StrictModes yes
```

And I get the error message `Directive 'StrictModes' is not allowed within a Match block`.  How may I overcome this or otherwise end up achieving my goal of knowing which node is which and what local port to use for SSH to the node?

Comment: I don't understand why you would have the same `authorized_keys` file for different users. How do you know that they're different origins if they're using the same key?

Comment: Question edited.  I want to have multiple keys in the same `authorized_keys` and differentiate the origin by what username is used when creating the tunnel (or by other means?).

Comment: I don't understand why you don't have a different key for each user.

Comment: I have different keys for each user, they are all put in the same `authorized_keys` file.  Like a lock, accepting more than one key, it is just that you have to tell the receptionist who you are before you test your key, if you tell the truth or not doesn't really matter as long as your key fit.

Comment: But why? It wouldn't cost more to have a different lock for each user. And if you don't want to have a different lock for each user then why have multiple users at all?

Comment: To know which node is which based on what they told server when making the reverse tunnel.  I could of course make a homedir and `authorized_keys` for each user, but I think that would make `/home/ ` look crowded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49969/discussion-between-wittrup-and-gilles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to distinguish between different connection origins, by giving them different users. It doesn't make sense to share the `authorized_keys` file between these different users, because then any of the keys would allow logging into any of the accounts. (It would *work*, but the account separation wouldn't give any security benefit.)

So have one `authorized_keys` file for each user, belonging to root. Each `authorized_keys` file authorizes only the key corresponding to that account. Creating multiple keys is cheap, there's no reason not to do it. You don't need to turn off `StrictModes`. You can use the `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive in a `Match` block for each user, or have a single `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive containing `%u` which is replaced by the username.

Tunnel users creation:

```
sudo groupadd sshtungrp
sudo mkdir /etc/ssh/tunnelkeys # or wherever you want to keep them
# Add users without /home
while read p; do sudo useradd $p -r -s /bin/true -g sshtungrp; done < users.txt;
# Copy key file with: sudo vim /etc/ssh/tunnelkeys/%u
```

sshd_config:

```
Match Group sshtungrp
        AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/tunnelkeys/%u
```